# facebook graph api in ios error- Unknown path components:

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using facebook graph api in ios to share a news feed from iphone. But i get the following error:

```
{com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 2500;
        message = "Unknown path components: /http://newswatch.nationalgeographic.com/2013/01/20/top-25-wild-bird-photographs-of-the-week-34;
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
```

}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}

following is part of my code to share a newsfeed on btnClick:

```
if ([strType isEqualToString:@"link"]) {


            text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"caption"];
            if (text == nil) {
                text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"name"];
            }
            if (text == nil) {
                text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"story"];
            }
            NSDictionary *dict = [resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];



            dic=[NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:text,@"message",nil];
            NSLog(@"%@", dict);
           // NSString *str = [dict valueForKey:@"link"];
            NSString *str = [dict valueForKey:@"link"];
            request=[NSMutableString stringWithString: @"me/feed/"];
            [request appendString:str];
             NSLog(@"appended : %@", request);
        }
```

same code works if i try to share a `photo` type of newsfeed.
where am i getting wrong? how do i solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i got the error:
correct code:

```
if ([strType isEqualToString:@"link"] || [strType isEqualToString:@"video"]) {


            text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"caption"];
            if (text == nil) {
                text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"name"];
            }
            if (text == nil) {
                text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"story"];
            }
            NSDictionary *dict = [resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

            NSLog(@"%@", dict);

            NSString *str = [dict valueForKey:@"link"];
            dic=[NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:str,@"link",nil];
            request=[NSMutableString stringWithString: @"me/feed/"];

             NSLog(@" %@", dic);
        }
```

in `request` we only need to pass `me/feed` and in `params` of `FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:request parameters:dic HTTPMethod:@"POST"];` we need to pass `link=http://...`